# Locked out of EC2 ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, root

root access worked on my EC2 instance for a couple of weeks until I did

> sudo aptitude update
>
> sudo aptitude upgrade

and now sudo asks for a password (which I have never been given). I can't log in as root (says "Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".").

Does anyone know a way out of this mess ?

**SOLVED**: the solution is here in the accepted response: [Amazon EC2 asking me to move AMI, how to go about doing it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/268537/amazon-ec2-asking-me-to-move-ami-how-to-go-about-doing-it)

Comment: Are you SSHing using your key?

Comment: Yes I'm using the .pem key generated from the ec2 management console

Comment: And you're connecting with the ubuntu user?  e.g. ssh -i <mykey> ubuntu@<myserver> ?

Comment: Yes that is how I'm connecting

Comment: Sounds like your sudoers file might have changed - do you have permission to see it?  /etc/sudoers

Comment: Nope permission denied

Comment: Can you see when it was last updated?  ls -l /etc | grep sudoers

Comment: It was updated 3 hours ago

Comment: So that looks like a possible cause of the problem.  Unfortunately there's no way to boot into single user mode on AWS.  I think you might have to restore from a snapshot.  I'm going to re-snapshot my EC2 machines right now!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Nothing substantial was lost but it still stings a little.

Comment: Can you set your own password using passwd?  Not sure why I didn't think of this before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your password by typing `passwd` when logged in as user `ubuntu`.  Once you've done this, you should be able to sudo using the same password - assuming the ubuntu user is still present in the sudoers file.

It sounds as though your sudoers file no longer allows sudo to operate without specifying a password.  Once you've got sudo access again, you can change the behaviour in the sudoers file:

```
/etc/sudoers
```

Uncomment the line which says:

```
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```