# Amazon EC2 asking me to move AMI, how to go about doing it?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Amazon is asking me to move to another AMI within 24 hours since the root password to the one I am one has gotten compromised (¿?).

**How do I go about moving to another instance?**

This setup was fairly specific, how do I make sure the next instance I use is compatible?

Will I lose my current processes? (minor issue)

Will I lose my crontab jobs? (minor issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon will be satisfied when the AMI-number changes. You can do this the easy way:

1. Shutdown your instance.
2. Create an AMI from your instance (Instance Actions > Create Image).
3. Create a new instance, based upon the newly created AMI.
4. Destroy the previous instance if everything is working as it should be.
5. Delete the AMI if you wish to

The instance will be identical to what you have now. But keep in mind that Amazon doesn't send these emails to annoy you, so change your root-pw.

Comment: Thanks. I did as you showed me and then created a root password, it sounds like that was my sin. Can you confirm this :) ?

Comment: Amazon mailed me the same thing a month ago because I used an AMI in which they had (accidently) set the root-pw. Amazon didn't like this so the AMI had to go. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help.. It was exactly what I was looking for